# Having two different databases in a Stripes webapp with Stripersist

Tags: stripes

I use Stripes framework with Stripersist.

I want my webapp to use two different databases : in my `persistence.xml`, I want two different `persistence-unit`.

How can I do that ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Since this hasn't been answered yet - it's very possible and easy.  I don't work with Stripes anymore, but simply add the persistence-unit to persistence.xml and use the overloaded Stripersist.getEntityManager method (I think it was).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple peristence units with `Stripersist`. Although you can no longer use the `getEntityManager()` method:

```
Stripersist.getEntityManager()
```

You need to use one of these:

```
Stripersist.getEntityManager("Your PU name")
```

Or:

```
Stripersist.getEntityManager(YourEntity.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally we removed Stripersist and build our own stack. We don't try the solution proposed by Kdeveloper.

First we wrote a Stripe interceptor :

```
@Intercepts({LifecycleStage.RequestInit, LifecycleStage.RequestComplete})
public class HibernateTxInterceptor implements net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.Interceptor {

private SessionFactory getUserSessionFactory(ExecutionContext context) {
  return (SessionFactory) context.getActionBeanContext().getServletContext().getAttribute(MyInitListener.CTX_SESSION_USERS);
}

private SessionFactory getDocumentSessionFactory(ExecutionContext context) {
  return (SessionFactory) context.getActionBeanContext().getServletContext().getAttribute(MyInitListener.CTX_SESSION_DOCUMENTS);
}


public Resolution intercept(ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {
  LifecycleStage stage = context.getLifecycleStage();
  if (stage == LifecycleStage.RequestInit) { 
    // Init transactions
    Transaction userTx = getUserSessionFactory(context).getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    Transaction documentTx = getDocumentSessionFactory(context).getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
  } else if (stage.equals(LifecycleStage.RequestComplete)) {
    // Commit Transactions
    Transaction userTx = getUserSessionFactory(context).getCurrentSession().getTransaction();
    userTx.commit();
    ...
    // Idem for documentTx...

  }
}
```

And we created a servlet listener to inject the two Hibernate session factories using Spring :

```
public class Reef4iInitListener implements ServletContextListener {
  public static final String CTX_SESSION_USERS = "user";
  public static final String CTX_SESSION_DOCUMENTS = "document";
  private ServletContext servletContext;

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
    servletContext = e.getServletContext();

    final WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(e.getServletContext());

    SessionFactory usersSessionFactory = (SessionFactory) springContext.getBean("usersSessionFactory");

    ... // do the same with for document factory
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {
    SessionFactory userTx = (SessionFactory) e.getServletContext().getAttribute(CTX_SESSION_USERS);
    userTx.close();
  .... // do the same for document factory
  }
```